# I don't understand this opcode in JVM Implementation

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, opcode, jvm-bytecode

I am writing a JVM.
I was implementing all opcodes one by one, until I faced `dup2`.
The oracle instruction set https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.dup2 says

> Duplicate the top one or two values on the operand stack and push the duplicated value or values back onto the operand stack in the original order

How am I supposed to choose which operation to perform?
How can I know when I should duplicate only the top or I should duplicate the top two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the opcode says:

> Form 1:
>
> ..., value2, value1 →
>
> ..., value2, value1, value2, value1
>
> where both value1 and value2 are values of a category 1 computational
> type (§2.11.1).
>
> Form 2:
>
> ..., value →
>
> ..., value, value
>
> where value is a value of a category 2 computational type (§2.11.1).

Category 2 types are `long` and `double`, and category 1 are others.  So in the original versions of Java Category 2 types meant 64 bit type and Category 1 meant 32 bit types.  When 64 bit JVMs were introduced, that distinction no longer worked.  Now an interpreter or JIT compiler needs to track the categories of values pushed and popped from the opstack to the extent that it knows whether the value on the top of stack is category 1 or 2.

Note that the JVM needs to this kind of analysis at verify time in order to check the requirements set out in 
[4.10.1.7. Type Checking Load and Store Instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.7)

Comment: The distinction of into category X computational type were a mistake. Premature optimization that doesn't work anymore. To have an easier implementation with 32-bit VMs, at the cost of keeping this distinction around forever.

Comment: I suspect that they weren't thinking that far ahead.  We don't know when dup2 was first introduced.  My guess would be that it was back in the Oak days ... when they were more focused on bytecode size and simplifying the interpreter than performance, planning for 64 bit, planning for JIT compilation, etc.

Comment: The decision for these two categories is in the same league as the alignment of switch instructions or letting `long` and `double` take two constant pool entries. The latter [even has a retrospective comment in the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.5-120) But we should not overestimate the impact of this on a modern JVM.